# 'Change the Look' not applying

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

On an account with Full Control over a SP Team Site I can go to Settings > 'Change the Look' and select say the orange theme (any theme has the same issue). This is not a spcolor custom theme, but one of the built-in themes.

To confirm the change, I refresh the page and the theme has applied:
[image]

When I now navigate to the test team site with a user with Read permission level, the theme does not apply:
[image]

I have added the user to Full Control but this does not apply the theme still but interestingly can now see the 'Change the Look' with the current theme selected correctly:
[image]

I would massively appreciate any pointers on where I can look. The Chrome or IE (happens in both) developer tools don't show any 404 or 401 returns, but I'm not 100% sure where to be looking in there as I haven't had too much experience with SP back-end.

Comment: Do other users with full control has this issue? try to add the site into IE Compatibility view and test again.

Comment: and also, check your farm build number. My environment is 16.0.10337.12109 , it could work well.

Comment: Other users will full control also look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYG7l.png - Farm build number is  16.0.10337.12109 - Compatibility mode makes no difference in IE.

Comment: Do other site collections has this issue? You can create a new site collection and test again. In addition, when you change a theme, go to Site settings->Themes->Themed, check if there is a folder created.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the pointer. The issue is reproduced on subsites within the new site collection. Anything else I can check/test? The 'Themed' folder is specified in Get-SPWeb (ThemedCssFolderUrl) and is accessible to the 'Read' user...